# How to upload server file to Dropbox via API

Tags: php, jquery, api, dropbox

How to upload file already existing on the server with free for acccess URL (http://www.example.com/files/test.pdf) to dropbox folder using their API.
I'm trying to do it with jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
        type: 'post',
        data: file,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN_KEY_HERE",
            "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/test_Delivery_note_digital/test.pdf","mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false}'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.error(data);
        }
    });
```

DROPBOX http documentation says that needs:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <get access token>" \
--header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/Homework/math/Matrices.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
--data-binary @local_file.txt
```

I found examples where there is an input/file and eg. on Change sends this file directly to dropbox, this works perfectly...

```
    $('#inputId').change(function(e) {
// ... file selected from a file <input>
file = e.target.files[0];
console.log(file);
```

when I pass **file** after I change the value of the file input it works as I said, without any actual upload. It's getting somehow all needed binary information about the file.

On console.log gives me:

```
File {name: "DeliveryNote_57D029F2-PO88.pdf", lastModified: 1490458856935, lastModifiedDate: Sat Mar 25 2017 18:20:56 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 31823…}
```

How to get the same information (json constructed) for any file on the server instead of passing through input/file?
Or is there any other way to pass (upload) a file from the server to dropbox?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question properly, but if you want to upload from a URL, you should use [/2/files/save_url](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-save_url) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, seems like definitely spent 8 hours for nothing.. I just had to use save_url ... (facepalm) Worked perfect like this.